# Error in lollypop music player

Tags: release-freya, thirdpartyapps

Update : New error. Check below.

I followed the default installation steps as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnumdk/lollypop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lollypop
```

But then got the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package lollypop
```

I followed the steps by @mike-wild which were :

```
$ git clone https://github.com/gnumdk/lollypop.git
$ cd lollypop
$ sudo apt install autoconf libglib2.0-dev intltool yelp-tools libgirepository1.0-dev libgtk-3-dev python3 python-cairo python-dbus python-gobject python-sqlite
$ ./autogen.sh
$ make
# sudo make install
```

This successfully installed(without any errors). But when I try to open it using the command "lollypop" in terminal.
I encountered this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/lollypop", line 22, in <module>
    from lollypop.application import Application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lollypop/application.py", line 16, in <module>
    gi.require_version('GstAudio', '1.0')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 79, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace GstAudio not available
```

EDIT 2 :

Running these:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0
```

After this lollypop opens up at least. But the gui crashes often. It is very unstable. This is the terminal output.

```
** (lollypop:8232): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus:    Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-36bSXu3dQ9: Connection refused
Namespace Secret not available
    - Scrobbler disabled
    - Auto cover download disabled
    - Artist informations disabled
$ sudo pip3 install pylast

(lollypop:8232): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkOverlay does not have a property called index
You are missing lollypop-portal: https://github.com/gnumdk/lollypop-portal GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Lollypop.Portal" does not exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lollypop/application.py", line 592, in __settings_dialog
    dialog = SettingsDialog()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lollypop/settings.py", line 169, in __init__
    h = grid.child_get_property(switch_artwork_tags, 'height')
TypeError: child_get_property() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Reading the above output, I went ahead and installed lollypop-portal: https://github.com/gnumdk/lollypop-portal through the steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/gnumdk/lollypop-portal.git
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

And then ran lollypop:

```
** (lollypop:9853): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus:      Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-36bSXu3dQ9: Connection refused
Namespace Secret not available
    - Scrobbler disabled
    - Auto cover download disabled
    - Artist informations disabled
$ sudo pip3 install pylast

(lollypop:9853): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkOverlay does not have a property called index
You are missing lollypop-portal: https://github.com/gnumdk/lollypop-portal GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name ":1.187"    does not exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-     packages/lollypop/application.py", line 592, in __settings_dialog
    dialog = SettingsDialog()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lollypop/settings.py", line 169, in __init__
    h = grid.child_get_property(switch_artwork_tags, 'height')
TypeError: child_get_property() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

So, should I install lollypop-portal before lollypop?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the author of the PPA you are using hasn't built Lollypop for Ubuntu 14.04 (which is what Freya is based on), which is why you are getting an error saying the package could not be located.

You can build it yourself using the instructions: https://github.com/gnumdk/lollypop, however I'm not sure if you'll be able to install the required dependencies in Freya.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/gnumdk/lollypop.git
$ cd lollypop
$ sudo apt install autoconf libglib2.0-dev intltool yelp-tools libgirepository1.0-dev libgtk-3-dev python3 python-cairo python-dbus python-gobject python-sqlite gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0

$ ./autogen.sh
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: It installed with only a minor change (sudo before make install). But isn't opening. When I enter "lollypop" comman in the terminal, this error is given: "ValueError: Namespace GstAudio not available"

Comment: That's something related to Gstreamer I think - I'll look into it.

Comment: @GauravKumar Can you run `sudo apt install gobject-introspection` and try again?

Comment: `gobject-introspection is already the newest version.`  Same error is popping up.

Comment: @GauravKumar Hmm, basically you are looking for a package which provides GstAudio-x.x.x.typelib, but I'm having problems figuring out which it is. Can you run `ls /usr/lib/girepository-1.0` and post the output?

Comment: If the directory is empty, then try installing `gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I did all you said, the error changed a little as I have edited above. I am starting to think it's impossible. :D

Comment: @GauravKumar I think you're almost there - you just need to find the package which will give you the right version of GstAudio. Possibly try posting on https://reddit.com/r/linuxquestions?

Comment: How can I find which version is required by lollypop?

Comment: You need GstAudio 1.0. I think I was wrong about installing `gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10`, you need `gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0`. Does that fix things? According to [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0/filelist) that package should have the correct version of GstAudio!

Comment: I just remembered that you're on Freya (Ubuntu 14.04) not Loki (Ubuntu 16.04). I have a feeling that the above package is too new for the 14.04 repos, so you might be out of luck here I'm afraid, unless you build Gstreamer 1.0 from source - but I can't help you there really.

Comment: Well well GstAudio error has gone! TotemPlParser error has crept up!

Comment: Please check the update. Is there anything I can do now? Else I'll just give up.

Comment: This is beyond my knowledge now unfortunately. If I had to guess I'd say that lollypop-portal wasn't actually running (hence the DBUS connection error you get) - so you need to figure out if the lollypop-portal service is running. If it's a systemd service then you can run `sudo systemctl start lollypop-portal`, otherwise I'm not sure.